# Setting Permissions to FIles and Folders on multiple levels in a windows share with powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions

This might be a little long, but it's a little tough to explain properly.

I built a new fileserver.  We made drastic changes to the security structure of the share compared to the original file share.  Users only have read access, 1 group has modify and Domain Admins have full control.

Under the share is numbered folders. There are 881 of them. In each of those folders is another set of folders based on a folder template.  The template permissions have been adjusted so any time it is copied and pasted into a new numbered folder it has the proper permissions.  The template does not allow inheritance.

My issues is on the existing 881 folders and the ones below.  When the data was copied, the securities did not come over properly or was rewritten to the shares permissions.  Regardless, I need to make the existing folder structure match the new template so everyone has the proper access.  Is there a way to write a powershell script to do this.  Below is an example of what the structure looks like and what I have to do.

```
-Share    
    -001            
      -Folder 1        
      -Folder 2        
      -Folder 3        
    -002    
      -Folder 1    
      -Folder 2    
      -Folder 3
```

I need to be able to add Group 1 to have modify on Folder 1 and it's files, Group 3 to have modify to Folder 2 and it's files and Group 7 to have modify to Folder 3 and it's files.

It's actually a little more complicated than that, but it's the general premise.  There are actually 26 folders under the numbered folder.  I need to change permissions on 9 of them.  4 of them are for the same group, but the rest are all different groups.  I also have to maintain the current permissions.

Is anyone this good with Powershell?  I am certainly not.

I do have a piece of software I am using to do this, but it is slow and cumbersome, as I have to select each numbered folder, then select the folders below that I need to change then go to the next numbered folder and so on.  It will change the permissions for all of them at once but I need to select them and it's taking a very long time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashtable to map folder->principal(s), then loop through all the root-level folders and apply the new ACEs:

```bsh
$principalMapping = @{
  'folder1' = @('Domain\Group1')
  'folder2' = @('Domain\Group3')
  'folder3' = @('Domain\Group7')
}

# Loop through all top level folders
foreach($topLevelFolder in Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\share\root\ -Directory){
  # Loop through each inner folder 
  foreach($innerFolder in $topLevelFolder |Get-ChildItem -Directory){
    # See if we have a corresponding entry in our mapping table
    if($principalMapping.ContainsKey($innerFolder.Name.ToLower())){
      # if so, obtain the current ACL
      $acl = Get-Acl $innerFolder.FullName

      # Loop through the list of groups to add (currently only one in each folder)
      foreach($principal in $principalMapping[$innerFolder.Name.ToLower()]){
        # Create your Access Control Entry
        $ace = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($principal, 'Modify', 'Allow')
        $acl.Add($ace)
      }

      # Update the ACL on the directory
      Set-Acl $innerFolder.FullName -AclObject $acl
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias.  I will try and see if I can get this going.  I really appreciate your help.